# How do have the JQuery UI Accordion preview some text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using the JQuery UI accordion plugin to show and hide blocks of text.  This works fine.  However, I was wondering how I could show some of the text under the header so that my users can get an idea of what is there rather than having to open each one and look?  For instance, it would be nice to show the first two `<p>` tags then allow them to click to see the rest.

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585586/creating-a-custom-accordion-effect-with-preview-of-text) but it works with a custom accordion and not the JQuery UI one which I would rather use.

Any ideas?

Comment: JQuery UI accordion by default uses css style display none and block to show and hide... So I recommend creating your own accordion

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was really hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging the jQ UI [tooltip widget](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/), you can grab the associated accordion content DIV when mousing over its sibling header and then load up a tooltip display whose contents include the child elements.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ewkLe/1/

In that demo, to show the first two `<p>` tags worth of content, I did the following:

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    $(document).tooltip({
        items: "#accordion > h3",
        content: function () {
            var ElemsToPreview = $(this).next().children().slice(0,2);
            var TooltipContents = '';
            $(ElemsToPreview).each(function(index) {
                TooltipContents += $(this).html();
                if(index==0)
                    TooltipContents += "<br/><br/>";
            });
            return "<div>" + TooltipContents + "</div>";
        }
    });
});
```

The `items` property allows me to set which items in the document should register tooltips while the `content` property allows me to define an anonymous function that dynamically generates the tooltip content.

Within that function I grab the first two children of the `<div>` that corresponds to that accordion section:

```
var ElemsToPreview = $(this).next().children().slice(0,2);
```

Then I grab the HTML contents of each of the two children and append them into a variable, with a line break in between to ensure they remain separated in the rendered tooltip;

```
var TooltipContents = '';
$(ElemsToPreview).each(function(index) {
    TooltipContents += $(this).html();
    if(index==0)
        TooltipContents += "<br/><br/>";
});
```

I then return a `<div>` that contains the tooltip contents I want:

```
return "<div>" + TooltipContents + "</div>";
```

Built from this markup:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque.</p>
        <p>Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sitamet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi.</p>
        <p>Proin viverra leo utodio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit ametpurus.</p>
        <p>Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitorvelit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus non quam. Insuscipit faucibus urna.</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.</p>
        <p>Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac liberoac tellus pellentesque semper.</p>
        <p>Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quislacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netuset malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis infaucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est.</p>
        <p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.</p>
        <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, perinceptos himenaeos.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```